# is it possible to create a Sharing from a snowflake Database?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sharing

is it possible to share a complete database on snowflake and share it on another snowflake account?

in order that all objects within the shared database are immediately visible in the snowflake subaccount

Comment: Did you try https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-sharing-intro.html? Something didn't work?

Comment: yes, should be but beware "Provider sharing is enabled by default for most, but not all accounts. If you encounter errors when attempting to share data with consumers, the feature may not be enabled for your account. To inquire about enabling it, please contact Snowflake Support." - https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Submit-a-Support-Case-in-Snowflake-Lodge

Comment: Hi Felipe, but the link don´t say database objects, only Tables, External tables, Secure views, Secure materialized views and Secure UDFs

Comment: You can only share secure views and tables. Any views not defined with the keyword "secure" are not sharable. When you create new objects, you'll need to share them. They won't automatically be shared. That would be a security concern, so it's not the default behavior.

Comment: If your use case can be supported with just tables and secure views then sharing is the easiest option. However if you do actually require a full copy of a DB, including all the objects it contains, then you should look at replication - there's a brief explanation of the replication process here: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-Copy-a-Database-from-One-account-to-Another